# legacy (classic) ASP code session issue

Tags: session, asp-classic

My question is about classic ASP, not ASP.Net. I ask expert here since search engine always tell me ASP.Net answers. My confusions are,

1. How to set session expiration time in classic ASP code or through configuration?
2. How to extend session expire time? Is there a session expire event?
3. How to know when session will expire?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Please pay attention to the suggest prompts when tagging your question.  Any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I must pay attention in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Please read this, I think it answers all your questions:

http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_sessions.asp

George,

There is a session_end event on the server side, but I suppose what you want is to detect it on client side.

To do that, you must set a timer on javascript, to end for example one minute before the session timeout and popup an alert. The alert gives the user the choice to extend the session. If the user says yes, then you make a post of the form (or an ajax call or anything that generates a request on the server side and so extends the session).

Comment: Seems not session end event and solutions to extend an expired session?

Comment: Thanks for your update, 1. could we extend session at server side when session expire? 2. "If the user says yes, then you make a post of the form (or an ajax call or anything that generates a request on the server side and so extends the session)." -- I do not want a solution which will force user to leave the page, I want to extend user session while at the same time let user retain to the same page to continue actions (e.g. editing a long document). Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The ajax call he is talking about, would not force you to leave the page.  You just need to generate some traffic to the site before your session expires so you can reset the timeout (now + 20 minutes).

Comment: @Zachary, appreciate if you could refer me some ready-to-use ajax samples. I did not got too much ideas about this solution until I see some workable code.

Answer (score 3):

George, ASP Classic sessions timeouts were finicky at best. I wouldn't rely on them. If you need to have more control over sessions I suggest you implement your own session management.

Comment: I am interested in what you mean -- "finicky at best"? Share some more insights and experiences? Currnetly I am maintaining some legacy code written by classic ASP, there is headache session expire issues...

Comment: Take a look: http://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=s&hl=en&q=asp+-.net+session+timeout&btnG=Google+Search 104,000 results for something that should be pretty straightforward? Something went terribly wrong. ;)

Comment: Is there a way to know when session will expire?

Answer (score 1):

Session.Timeout = 5           'five minutes

The session will expire after the number of minutes you've specified with no activity.  For instance, if you set a session variable, and the user doesn't do anything (like refresh) for 5 minutes, then the session will be abandoned by the server.

Or, you can abandon it yourself using Session.Abandon

Comment: Is there a session end event? Could we extend session expire time?

Comment: Dont think you can find out when the session is going to expire bcos if say for ex. if the session timeout is 20 mins and the user is inactive for a period of say 19 mins and only 1 min is left and he/she clicks on the app, the session is valid for 20 mins more since it was activated.

Comment: There might be a session end event in the Global.asa, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I find it, on session end event.

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you can find out when the session is going to expire bcos if say for ex. if the session timeout is 20 mins and the user is inactive for a period of say 19 mins and only 1 min is left and he/she clicks on the app, the session is valid for 20 mins more since it was activated.

Comment: What I mean is, is it possible to know when if user does not active operate on the page, when (i.e. how much idle time left) session will expire?

Comment: Thats what I have mentioned..It is hard to find that out but have heard that you can use AJAX to ping back the server...dont know exactly how to achieve it...

Comment: Have a look at this link
http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/07/05/1120592884938.html

Comment: Looks like an interesting article :
http://www.pascarello.com/AjaxSessionTimer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Store the session cookie in your database instead of relying on the default classic asp session storage. Once stored in the database, you can keep it valid for as long as you like.

In my opinion, it's too easy to lose your session with ASP classic.